# HTACCESS: Throw 404 error but still accessible

Tags: .htaccess

**I have the following structure:**

```
- root
  - css
    - test.css
  - index.php
```

Is there a way to throw a 404 error when I try to open **anything in CSS folder** in my browser as:

```
http://localhost:1993/css
http://localhost:1993/css/test.css
```

but still accessible from the browser? I want CSS to load normally, but to throw a 404 error when someone opens this path. Or turn off the directory listing for everything in the directory (with all files inside)? Or something like that? Its possible?

Comment: You can't by using htaccess because there is no way to know if someone tries to access it directly in a browser

Comment: Its a pity, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try [mod_access](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html),

```
<FilesMatch "\.css$">
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from 127.0.0.1
    allow from localhost
</FilesMatch>
```

With mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^!localhost
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/css [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.css$
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]
```

Comment: But this does not work if I upload it to the web. I only have access to the css folder and not the other users who do not read CSS (sry for bad English)

Comment: Try this in css folder's .htaccess

Comment: What is the exact error are you not able to include them in your file

Comment: I want a 404 error for anyone who tries to access the / css folder or direct access to the /css/test.css file. Just block the folder and the content inside, but still the browser can normally load the CSS. With this rules, they have 403 forbidden

Comment: Try now in css folder with mod rewrite solution edited in answer

Comment: CSS is not being loaded at all with this for anyone